# time offset from UTC to local time

Tags: r, timezone

I would like to know the time offset from UTC to local time on a particular day (eventually for all days in 2019) for all time zones in the world.

I tried the following code in R but it did not work:

```
library(lutz)

time_zones <- OlsonNames()

for (tz in time_zones) {
  temp <- rbind(
    tz_offset("2019-01-01", tz = tz),
  )
}
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: You need to define `temp` as an empty vector, e.g. `temp <- c()`, outside the loop, and `temp <- rbind(temp, tz_offset("2019-01-01", tz = tz))` in the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(lutz)

time_zones <- OlsonNames()

temp <- list()
for (tz in time_zones) {
  temp[[tz]] <- tz_offset("2019-01-01", tz = tz)
}

temp <- do.call(rbind, temp)
head(temp)
#                              tz_name           date_time zone is_dst utc_offset_h
#Africa/Abidjan         Africa/Abidjan 2019-01-01 00:00:00  GMT  FALSE            0
#Africa/Accra             Africa/Accra 2019-01-01 00:00:00  GMT  FALSE            0
#Africa/Addis_Ababa Africa/Addis_Ababa 2018-12-31 21:00:00  EAT  FALSE            3
#Africa/Algiers         Africa/Algiers 2018-12-31 23:00:00  CET  FALSE            1
#Africa/Asmara           Africa/Asmara 2018-12-31 21:00:00  EAT  FALSE            3
#Africa/Asmera           Africa/Asmera 2018-12-31 21:00:00  EAT  FALSE            3
```

Comment: Thank you! How could I extend this code to have a long list of all days from January 1st 2019 until December 31st 2023?

Comment: Nest the loop in another loop over all these dates?

Comment: ok, how does this look in practice?

Comment: Well, I'd say it looks easy. :)

Comment: sorry I don't get it- can you pls elaborate?

Comment: I think it works by modiying this:
temp[[tz]] <- tz_offset(seq(as.Date("2019-01-01"), as.Date("2023-12-31"), by = "days"), tz = tz)